# Display text in new line textarea in MVC razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a textarea in my mvc application when the user save it for example

```
hi
how are
you
```

but when user want to edit that textarea it shows

```
hi how are you
```

but i want in that way

```
hi 
how are 
you
```

I have tried

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Name", required = "required", @rows = 5 })
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. If your have 3 lines of text in the `textarea` and are saving it correctly, then read that back into a textarea, it will be displayed as 3 lines of text

Comment: You can't save newline character via textarea. for that you need to use editorfor with razor

Comment: where i will use your code i am not clear your solution

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers, Of course you can _save newline character via textarea_ (that's the whole purpose of a textarea - to create multiple lines of text)

Comment: My guess is something is going on to remove the newline characters and so the only way is to debug and see when Notes is populated, does the model have the newlines from the controller?

Comment: you are right in the model i mean in the database   @Html.TextArea("Note1", null,new { @class = "form-control" }) is saving the data as follows hihoware you how to save it as a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace each whitespace with a new line character

Edit the `ActionResult` so that when you save, you replace each `" "` with `Environment.NewLine`

like so:

```
NoteManager.Save(note.Replace(" ", Environment.NewLine));
```

**EDIT**

To replace 1st and last space with newline:

```
// set string
string s = "hi how are you";

// make sure that there are no trailing spaces otherwise our code will not work
s = s.TrimEnd(' ');

// remove 1st space
// get index
int index = s.IndexOf(" ");
// remove space
s = s.Remove(index, 1);
// replace with newline
s = s.Insert(index, Environment.NewLine);

// remove last space
// get index
index = s.LastIndexOf(" ");
// remove space
s = s.Remove(index, 1);
// replace with newline
s = s.Insert(index, Environment.NewLine);

Console.Write(s);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kg7kcf

Comment: That would give 4 lines of text! (and if OP has saved the value correctly, there is no need to do anything)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - now he edited the question. it took me a while to understand what the problem was. he's not making it easy for me... I had a completely different answer to begin with. he was asking for the default value

Comment: Ted i think u now understood now please give me the solution

Comment: @RakibAhmed - do you want the 1st and last space replaced with newline Rakib?

Comment: @Ted i want my edited quesstion answer could u give me the solution

Comment: @RakibAhmed - I just have. See after the EDIT